# Saving sublayers of route layer to disk using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst

I want to calculate a route consisting of 4 points with a script tool and save the results to disk. I need the route to appear as layer on ArcCatalog for continuing working with it (modification of its attribute table).
The script tool completes successfully but no output is saved.
So, I tried to add the Save To Layer File tool.

I receive the following error message:

> *File "C:\Users\Manu\Desktop\SS 2015\Analyse mit GI-Technologien\Abgabe\gruppe1\Teil1_240915.py", line 84, in 
>       arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile(outNALayer,outLayerFile,"","CURRENT")
>    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6640, in SaveToLayerFile
>       raise e
>
>   ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>   Failed to execute (SaveToLayerFile).*

This is my code:

```
#Create a new Route layer.  
outRouteResultObject=arcpy.na.MakeRouteLayer(in_network_dataset,out_network_analysis_layer=outNALayerName,impedance_attribute=impedanceAttribute,find_best_order="USE_INPUT_ORDER",accumulate_attribute_name=["Length"],output_path_shape="TRUE_LINES_WITH_MEASURES")
#Get the layer object from the result object. The route layer can now be referenced using the layer object.
outNALayer=outRouteResultObject.getOutput(0)

#Get the names of all the sublayers within the route layer.
subLayerNames=arcpy.na.GetNAClassNames(outNALayer)
#Store the layer names that we will use later
stopsLayerName=subLayerNames["Stops"]
routeLayerName=subLayerNames["Routes"]    


fieldMappings=arcpy.na.NAClassFieldMappings(outNALayer,stopsLayerName)
fieldMappings["RouteName"].mappedFieldName="stopover"

arcpy.na.AddLocations(outNALayer,stopsLayerName,"Stations",fieldMappings,"","Order","SNAP")
arcpy.na.Solve(outNALayer)

arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile(outNALayer,outLayerFile,"","CURRENT")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are almost there with your code. You just need to [retrieve the routing result sublayer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-network-analyst/routesolverproperties.htm) from your solved Routing Analysis layer, and then [save it](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm) to a permanent location on disk:

```
#....starting here from your code above

# Get a path to the routes sub layer
outNARoutesSubLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(outNALayer, subLayerNames["Routes"])[0] 

# Proceed with solving the layer as you were before...
arcpy.na.AddLocations(outNALayer,stopsLayerName,"Stations",fieldMappings,"","Order","SNAP")
arcpy.na.Solve(outNALayer)

# Save the resulting route polyline (the Routes Sublayer) to disk
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outNARoutesSubLayer, "Output_Routing_FeatureClass")
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jim!!!! It works perfectly. You made two students very happy. We were working on this problem for days.